# Why do Joda DateTimeZone names not return what I pass in?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

If I call `DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Ljubljana")` then I get back a `DateTimeZone`.

If I then look at that object's ID it's `"Europe/Belgrade"`.

I appreciate that these two places may well be in the same timezone, but if a user has selected `"Europe/Ljubljana"` then I'd like to be able to pass this back to them, and it's lost if I store data as a `DateTimeZone`.

Is there a way around that?

Comment: Try using getName() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TZDB data, `Europe/Ljubljana` is a "link" (or "alias") to `Europe/Belgrade`.  It is not a distinct zone of its own.  You can see it in the data [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/b8e081b8bae00f6939103b15657591af5856ddce/europe#L2475).

Joda Time does not retain the original ID string passed in once it resolves it to a particular zone.  If you require that, then you'll have to persist that string in your own separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**
You can use this auxiliary class:

```
public final class DateTimeZoneExtended
{
   public final DateTimeZone dateTimeZone;
   public final String tzName;

   private DateTimeZoneExtended(String id, DateTimeZone zone)
   {
      tzName = id;
      dateTimeZone = zone;
   }

   public static DateTimeZoneExtended forID(String id)
   {
      return new DateTimeZoneExtended(id, DateTimeZone.forID(id));
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTimeZoneExtended dtz = DateTimeZoneExtended.forID("Europe/Ljubljana");
```

Now you can use `dtz.dateTimeZone` to get joda's `DateTimeZone`, and `dtz.name` to get name